# POS Printer not detected by POS.NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, point-of-sale

Recently bought a POS Printer (off-brand from China) and I'm want to write a little WPF application that will let me print some text and cut the thermal paper.

I installed POS.NET hoping that it would work out the box but it doesn't seem that way (go figure).

I've been reading about trying to gather some information to understand the problem better but I'm a bit stumped on what's going wrong.

I've already installed the drivers required for the printer and the device does appear in device manager. The test app that came with the printer also works, but I just can't get POS.NET to recognise that it exists.

The brand of POS Printer is called Excelvan (or Hoin) POS-80-Series

Anyone willing to educate me on how this works, where I'm going wrong and what concepts I'm misunderstanding about POS.NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To handle devices with POS for .NET, you need a software component called a service object.
It needs to be made according to the interface specification of POS for .NET or OPOS.
This will be different from the standard Windows Device Driver.
And on printers, service objects are often exclusively used with Windows Device Driver.

Please refer to this site.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429017(v=winembedded.4).aspx

Service objects are usually provided by the hardware vendor.
Since only Windows Device Driver is released to the site of the printer vendor that you are asking, it is thought that the printer can not be used from POS for .NET.
http://hoinprinter.com/en/download

If you use that printer, please control it through the Windows standard print API.

If you want to print from POS for .NET, switch to the printer of the vendor that provides the service object.